# PHPUnit runs on Terminal but not in NetBeans

Tags: php, unix, netbeans, terminal, mamp

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 w/ bitnami mampstack 5.4.11 (PHP 5.4.11) and NetBeans 7.2.1.
Since I've switched from XAMPP (for Mac) w/ PHP 5.3.x to 5.4+ NB can't use PHPUnit or any other bash script.
PHPUnit is up and running and works like a charm via Terminal. But in NB I get this:

```
/Applications/mampstack-5.4.11/php/bin/phpunit: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory
```

Looks like php didn't interprete the actual php code ... I've no idea why this happens and how to fix this.

Some setup details:

- My mampstack is located at /Applications/mampstack-5.4.11/
- php interpreter is set to /Applications/mampstack-5.4.11/php/bin/php within NB config
- include paths are set and working in php as well as in NB
- path to php binary within PHPUnit bash script is correct (/Applications/mampstack-5.4.11/php/bin/php)
- none of the scripts that go like #!/path/to/php/executable \n  work within NB anymore

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Also postet this question on the [NetBeans Forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=143120).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by creating a phpunit.sh and phpunit-skelgen.sh within [...]/php/bin with

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/mampstack-5.4.11/php/bin/php /Applications/mampstack-5.4.11/php/bin/phpunit "$@"
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/mampstack-5.4.11/php/bin/php /Applications/mampstack-5.4.11/php/bin/phpunit-skelgen "$@"
```

and ponting to it within NetBeans config.

Thanks to victor ♦♦ from bitnami answers.